# Unable to install magic-1.1 for iHaskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, cabal-install

## Main Issue

I am new to Haskell and I wanna use [iHaskell](https://github.com/IHaskell/IHaskell), an interactive Haskell similar to Jupyter notebook in Python. I noticed that the `magic` library is missing after running `stack install --fast` . Therefore, I run `stack install magic-1.1 --extra-include-dirs {$HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/include --extra-lib-dirs {$HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/lib` on the fish shell in my M1 Max MacBook. However, the error still occurred as follow

```
stack install magic-1.1 --extra-include-dirs {$HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/include --extra-lib-dirs {$HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/lib
magic> configure
magic> Warning: magic.cabal:27:28: version operators used. To use version operators
magic> the package needs to specify at least 'cabal-version: >= 1.8'.
magic> Configuring magic-1.1...
magic> Cabal-simple_SvXsv1f__3.6.3.0_ghc-9.2.7: Missing dependency on a foreign
magic> library:
magic> * Missing (or bad) C library: magic
magic> This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
magic> provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
magic> already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
magic> --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.If the
magic> library file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
magic> compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
magic> with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
magic>

Error: [S-7282]
       Stack failed to execute the build plan.

       While executing the build plan, Stack encountered the following errors:

       [S-7011]
       While building package magic-1.1 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
       [A long string of dir here and I do not shown here for neatness  ]
       Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

How can I fix this error?

## Installation Detail and Similar Case

I installed `ghcup` using home-brew and then installed `Stack, HLS, cabal, GHC`
using `ghcup tui`. I find a similar discussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/jr9fqi/haskell_error_while_configuring_haskell_notebook/). The problem may be that the `pkg-config` cannot see `libmagic` though I installed them using homebrew.

Comment: You're not following the Readme of IHaskell w.r.t. installing packages: to get a package installed, you need to add it to the stack.yaml file https://github.com/IHaskell/IHaskell#where-are-my-packages-ihaskell--stack Never do `stack install package` to get libraries: this command only meant to be used for packages containing executables. Lastly, the magic library was last updated in 2014: it probably doesn't work.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn, thanks for the information of stack.yaml. I read the detail of yaml configuration. To fix this problem I downloaded magic-1.1 file and put it inside IHaskell directory. Then I add ```. /magic-1.1``` into the ```package``` in stack.yaml. However, it does not help. What exactly should I do to install IHaskell probably?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

After struggling for a few hours, I found that the solution was to add path variables in the `stack install --fast`. For Apple Silicon and HomeBrew users, the brew directory locates at  `/opt/homebrew/` and for stack to see `pkg-config` or `libmagic`, we need to add additional flags into the stack install command. This instruction was clearly stated on the Github page `--extra-include-dirs ${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/include --extra-lib-dirs ${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/lib` but I did not change the variable name `${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}`. After changing it back to `/opt/homebrew` to works fine.